# Unable to Mount C Drive (could mount other NTFS drives)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

My problem is a little different than usual. I'm unable to mount just one of the NTFS drives. C:\ drive, which contains windows. I can perfectly mount other NTFS drives in the same hard disk. Previously I could mount all the drives including C drive.

I disabled fast startup. Booted into Ubuntu by restarting the PC. I've also lifted the default security for C drive in windows. I'm clue less as to what to do now. please help.

There is no error displayed when I try to mount C drive, just nothing happens.

when I try to run 'sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda4' I get the following.

```
Mounting volume... Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted
```

but the windows is not hibernated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha I did not hibernate or fast start, and I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Have you disabled fast start in Windows? If yes, shutdown your windows by this command in CMD: `shutdown /s`

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha I did try 'shutdown /s' . Nothing is working.

Comment: If you have disabled fast start and still you face with this problem, you need to disable hibernate in Windows. I think the instruction is in that question too. If you cannot find, let me know